# Combining the bookmark JSON files from Chome and Edge Chromium into one file using PowerShell?

Tags: json, powershell, google-chrome, microsoft-edge, bookmarks

We are migrating from Chrome to Edge Chromium (and when Microsoft puts the final nail into the IE 11 coffin from IE 11 as well). This is being done when PCs are being replaced.

We are using USMT to copy users files over. So the old computer may or may not have Chrome, but if it does, I'd like to copy the bookmark files. If it has Edge installed too (most do), I'd like to copy those bookmarks too. When restoring the USMT data, I'd like to add a step to our restore script that merges the results of both of the bookmark files into one JSON file and import it into Edge Chromium (I think I can just plop the "Bookmarks" file into "C:\Users$UserID\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default").

I have these three functions that get called in other parts of the script:

```
Function Backup-ChromeBookmarks {
  $pathToChromeJsonFile = -join("C:\Users\", $UserID, "\AppData\local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Bookmarks")
  $global:chromeBookmarkExists = Test-Path $pathToChromeJsonFile
  if ($chromeBookmarkExists -eq $true){
    Copy-Item -Path $pathToChromeJsonFile -Destination $BackupStore/Bookmarks-chrome.json
  }
}

Function Backup-EdgeBookmarks {
  $pathToEdgeJsonFile = -join("C:\Users\", $UserID, "\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default\Bookmarks")
  $global:edgeBookmarkExists = Test-Path $pathToEdgeJsonFile
  if ($edgeBookmarkExists -eq $true){
    Copy-Item -Path $pathToEdgeJsonFile -Destination $BackupStore/Bookmarks-edge.json

  }
}

Function Combine-Bookmarks {
  # referenced https://www.jonathanmedd.net/2020/04/combine-two-json-files-with-powershell.html
  #https://web.archive.org/web/20200517182000/https://www.jonathanmedd.net/2020/04/combine-two-json-files-with-powershell.html
  if($chromeBookmarkExists -eq $true -And $edgeBookmarkExists -eq $true){

    $data1 = Get-Content $BackupStore/Bookmarks-chrome.json -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
    $data2 = Get-Content $BackupStore/Bookmarks-edge.json -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
  
   
    
    $data1.psobject.Properties | ForEach-Object {
      $data2 | Add-Member -MemberType $_.MemberType -Name $_.Name -Value $_.Value -Force
       
    }
    @($data2) | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File $BackupStore/Bookmarks
  }
}
```

It works to copy the "Bookmarks" files from Chrome and Edge, but when it combines them and writes the file, this is all the contents are:

```
    "checksum":  "0f9bf8e97b9ac6cd3654c15c673b8cb8",
    "roots":  {
                  "bookmark_bar":  {
                                       "children":  "                                                                              ",
                                       "date_added":  "13252082948039886",
                                       "date_modified":  "13268156238031255",
                                       "guid":  "0bc5d13f-2cba-5d74-951f-3f233fe6c908",
                                       "id":  "1",
                                       "name":  "Bookmarks bar",
                                       "type":  "folder"
                                   },
                  "other":  {
                                "children":  "",
                                "date_added":  "13252082948040297",
                                "date_modified":  "0",
                                "guid":  "82b081ec-3dd3-529c-8475-ab6c344590dd",
                                "id":  "2",
                                "name":  "Other bookmarks",
                                "type":  "folder"
                            },
                  "synced":  {
                                 "children":  "",
                                 "date_added":  "13252082948040301",
                                 "date_modified":  "0",
                                 "guid":  "4cf2e351-0e85-532b-bb37-df045d8f8d0f",
                                 "id":  "3",
                                 "name":  "Mobile bookmarks",
                                 "type":  "folder"
                             }
              },
    "version":  1
}
```

Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong with merging the two JSON files? I don't have a lot of experience with this and would appreciate any feedback.

Please let me know if I'm missing any info. Thanks!

Here are some random bookmark lists from Chrome and Edge for sample data:
Chrome

```
   "checksum": "0e3450f30154cec188275de0e1eed2a5",
   "roots": {
      "bookmark_bar": {
         "children": [ {
            "date_added": "13282342589274138",
            "guid": "dff3def7-9693-443c-a44c-2b1047687b33",
            "id": "5",
            "name": "Google News",
            "type": "url",
            "url": "https://news.google.com/topstories?hl=en-CA&gl=CA&ceid=CA:en"
         }, {
            "children": [ {
               "date_added": "13282342602339055",
               "guid": "3a6114ed-d13a-491e-a049-d47a174a349b",
               "id": "7",
               "name": "reddit - Google Search",
               "type": "url",
               "url": "https://www.google.com/search?q=reddit&oq=reddit&aqs=chrome..69i57j46i131i199i433i465i512j0i131i433i512l3j0i131i433j0i131i433i512l3.1205j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8"
            }, {
               "date_added": "13282342613505854",
               "guid": "0da478c1-a91b-4af9-80db-cae8dc6927c0",
               "id": "8",
               "name": "Reddit - Dive into anything",
               "type": "url",
               "url": "https://www.reddit.com/"
            }, {
               "date_added": "13282342620306591",
               "guid": "b0311e2e-a41f-47fa-a1ef-214dd3964729",
               "id": "9",
               "name": "Facebook - Log In or Sign Up",
               "type": "url",
               "url": "https://www.facebook.com/"
            }, {
               "date_added": "13282342631549806",
               "guid": "a06637af-50be-458e-95bc-730ffc1cda36",
               "id": "10",
               "name": "Instagram",
               "type": "url",
               "url": "https://www.instagram.com/?hl=en"
            } ],
            "date_added": "13282342597429656",
            "date_modified": "13282342644382518",
            "guid": "a5b18126-11f7-40df-809f-2d96f311f1f6",
            "id": "6",
            "name": "Test Folder",
            "type": "folder"
         }, {
            "date_added": "13282342644382518",
            "guid": "39ef0ac5-b70c-406e-acea-96c3f90935ef",
            "id": "11",
            "name": "Dogpile.com",
            "type": "url",
            "url": "https://www.dogpile.com/"
         }, {
            "date_added": "13282342655028948",
            "guid": "d152f027-2aae-47b1-bae6-f9d7e617b639",
            "id": "12",
            "name": "Ask.com - What's Your Question?",
            "type": "url",
            "url": "https://www.ask.com/"
         } ],
         "date_added": "13282342511050735",
         "date_modified": "13282342655028948",
         "guid": "0bc5d13f-2cba-5d74-951f-3f233fe6c908",
         "id": "1",
         "name": "Bookmarks bar",
         "type": "folder"
      },
      "other": {
         "children": [  ],
         "date_added": "13282342511050739",
         "date_modified": "0",
         "guid": "82b081ec-3dd3-529c-8475-ab6c344590dd",
         "id": "2",
         "name": "Other bookmarks",
         "type": "folder"
      },
      "synced": {
         "children": [  ],
         "date_added": "13282342511050740",
         "date_modified": "0",
         "guid": "4cf2e351-0e85-532b-bb37-df045d8f8d0f",
         "id": "3",
         "name": "Mobile bookmarks",
         "type": "folder"
      }
   },
   "version": 1
}
```

Edge

```
{
   "checksum": "c26640ae81258f8bb73935ccd2bb1e91",
   "roots": {
      "bookmark_bar": {
         "children": [ {
            "date_added": "13282342518391441",
            "guid": "00f514ec-8d15-45b1-9c26-ba258d59c688",
            "id": "9",
            "name": "Google News",
            "show_icon": false,
            "source": "user_add",
            "type": "url",
            "url": "https://news.google.com/topstories?hl=en-CA&gl=CA&ceid=CA:en"
         }, {
            "date_added": "13282342527623442",
            "guid": "f690f411-6f29-4e22-bee4-d57b225a9287",
            "id": "10",
            "name": "Stack Overflow - Where Developers Learn, Share, & Build Careers",
            "show_icon": false,
            "source": "user_add",
            "type": "url",
            "url": "https://stackoverflow.com/"
         }, {
            "children": [ {
               "date_added": "13282342544239807",
               "guid": "bf6d87ae-9cd1-4d02-b2de-5083e9b487f1",
               "id": "12",
               "name": "Amazon.ca: Low Prices – Fast Shipping – Millions of Items",
               "show_icon": false,
               "source": "user_add",
               "type": "url",
               "url": "https://www.amazon.ca/"
            }, {
               "date_added": "13282342551951302",
               "guid": "d504da5d-4217-4a79-998c-f3dd5b0c95e0",
               "id": "13",
               "name": "Best Buy: Shop Online For Deals & Save | Best Buy Canada",
               "show_icon": false,
               "source": "user_add",
               "type": "url",
               "url": "https://www.bestbuy.ca/en-ca"
            }, {
               "date_added": "13282342564797804",
               "guid": "cad2d5d7-c72e-477e-854a-d58df397574c",
               "id": "15",
               "name": "Laptops, Desktops, Tablets, Computer Components, Printers, TVs, Video Games & Appliances - Canada Computers & Electronics",
               "show_icon": false,
               "source": "user_add",
               "type": "url",
               "url": "https://www.canadacomputers.com/"
            } ],
            "date_added": "13282342538649786",
            "date_modified": "13282342564797804",
            "guid": "3616a33e-7bf6-47de-8142-673cc19f6d64",
            "id": "11",
            "name": "Shopping",
            "source": "unknown",
            "type": "folder"
         } ],
         "date_added": "13282342417969383",
         "date_modified": "13282342544239807",
         "guid": "0bc5d13f-2cba-5d74-951f-3f233fe6c908",
         "id": "1",
         "name": "Favorites bar",
         "source": "unknown",
         "type": "folder"
      },
      "other": {
         "children": [  ],
         "date_added": "13282342417969428",
         "date_modified": "0",
         "guid": "82b081ec-3dd3-529c-8475-ab6c344590dd",
         "id": "2",
         "name": "Other favorites",
         "source": "unknown",
         "type": "folder"
      },
      "synced": {
         "children": [  ],
         "date_added": "13282342417969430",
         "date_modified": "0",
         "guid": "4cf2e351-0e85-532b-bb37-df045d8f8d0f",
         "id": "3",
         "name": "Mobile favorites",
         "source": "unknown",
         "type": "folder"
      }
   },
   "version": 1
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `@($data2) | ConvertTo-Json`? In the `Add-Member` line you are adding properties from `data1` to `data2`, so the latter will contain the merged data.

Comment: Thanks @zett42, good catch. I tried that suggestion but the results don't include both files. I get the exact same output file.

FYI, I made an edit to my above code because my $pathToEdgeJsonFile and $pathToChromeJsonFile vars both were referencing the Chrome bookmarks JSON file.

Comment: Please also correct the logic error that @zett42 pointed out in the code in your question. Note that [`ConvertTo-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json) - unfortunately - limits the serialization depth to 2 child levels by default, which can result in _quiet truncation_ of data. Try adding, say, `-Depth 10`. Also, do both input JSON files really contain just _one_ object each?

Comment: Having had another look at your code, you are merging only the top-level properties of the JSON ("checksum", "roots" and "version"). So `$data2` will have these completely overwritten by `$data1`. Correctly merging the files will need recursion. Can you add samples of the input datas, that showcases the nested structures?

Comment: have added some examples above. This only has the bookmark bar folder with 1 level of folder underneath it, but presumably users could have more bookmarks buried deeper.

Both of the files have many, many bookmarks (more than my samples above)—not just one object. I corrected the other logic error and added in some sample data. I'll try the -Depth 10 parameter to see if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 2):

As @zetta42 points out, it is likely that you just need to add more depth:

```
@($data2) | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10 | Out-File $BackupStore/Bookmarks
```

as well as overwriting the `roots` property (not actually merging).

However, from a user experience you may want to consider another update. Right now if the two contain bookmarks of the same `name`, your *intended* merge logic will overwrite one with the other. A user (you) may be a whole lot happier knowing which browser a given bookmark came from and can easily re-organize from within the new browser (or, since I am not familiar with it, hopefully it does) if not desired. So I would suggest grabbing the the two bookmarks and putting them under their own folders in the new bookmarks. Something like the following:

```
Function Combine-Bookmarks {
  # referenced https://www.jonathanmedd.net/2020/04/combine-two-json-files-with-powershell.html
  #https://web.archive.org/web/20200517182000/https://www.jonathanmedd.net/2020/04/combine-two-json-files-with-powershell.html
  if($chromeBookmarkExists -eq $true -And $edgeBookmarkExists -eq $true){

    $data1 = Get-Content $BackupStore/Bookmarks-chrome.json -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
    $data2 = Get-Content $BackupStore/Bookmarks-edge.json -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json

    $dataNew = @{
      'roots'=@{'Chrome'=$data1.Roots; 'IE'=$data2.Roots}
      #whatever the structure of the new json file should be
    }
    $dataNew | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10 | Out-File $BackupStore/Bookmarks_new.json
  }
}
```

Also you can either leave a folder blank if they don't have that browser, or you can exclude it from the `$dataNew` (by using a bit of different syntax I don't recall). Right now it will only attempt a merge if both exist.

Comment: I really like the idea of putting them into two separate folders so they know what browser they came from. When I tried your second block of code, I got this "null" output

{
    "roots":  {
                  "Chrome":  null,
                  "IE":  null
              }
}

Any idea what I'm missing there?

Comment: Umm...I did not have a chance to test my code, sorry about that. Assuming that you placed the code in the correct part of your script, I would imagine I misinterpreted the structure of the `json` file. Maybe it is `$data1.value.roots` or `$data1.roots.bookmark_bar.children` or something; the tree path depends on the tree structure of the file and which values you want to grab.

Comment: There is a line cut off from your `json` examples...

Comment: I don't see any lines that are cut off when I compare it with my original files (Chrome Bookmark: https://rentry.co/pye46 Edge bookmarks: https://rentry.co/c5ixu). I'm really not that familiar with JSON. Is the formatting of this maybe not conforming to JSON standards?   Edit: Sorry for the delay in my reply I had some other more urgent work pop up in the mean time

Comment: Ah, the starting brace (`{`) was not rendering for me. The file looks good and I manually did a smoke test with the content of your `rentry.co/pye46` and everything worked fine for me the way I have it. Maybe `$BackupStore` is not populated? I am not sure at this point.