# Adding entries to JSON Bookmarks file with powershell

Tags: json, powershell, bookmarks

So i have reviewed and tested the code in [Combining the bookmark JSON files from Chome and Edge Chromium into one file using PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70114284/combining-the-bookmark-json-files-from-chome-and-edge-chromium-into-one-file-usi) which was very handy to understand some things about JSON and powershell.

I have Chrome's and Edge's bookmarks exported into 2 discreet files by using the code in the link.
Now the problem i have is that if i combine the 2 it is changing the format for the new bookmark file is not properly readable by edge.

Ideally what I need to do is re-write the file adding entries to specific nodes (i am not sure about the JSON nomeclature so please excuse my ignorance)

So an Edge/Chrome bookmark file looks like:

```
{
   "checksum": "555e69b0181a1a30d58cc3fff59f7dad",
   "roots": {
      "bookmark_bar": {
         "children": [ {
            "date_added": "13301408662223632",
            "guid": "7b8047d6-eb01-4629-a960-a81307fbb0b0",
            "id": "17",
            "name": "Home - BBC News",
            "type": "url",
            "url": "https://www.bbc.co.uk/news"
         }, {
            "date_added": "13301408702331979",
            "guid": "eb1d3e92-eb5a-4011-a6ea-e6f15ec9a58a",
            "id": "20",
            "name": "Your stream on SoundCloud",
            "type": "url",
            "url": "https://soundcloud.com/stream"
         } ],
         "date_added": "13301408646379132",
         "date_modified": "13301408702331979",
         "guid": "0bc5d13f-2cba-5d74-951f-3f233fe6c908",
         "id": "1",
         "name": "Bookmarks bar",
         "type": "folder"
      },
      "other": {
         "children": [  ],
         "date_added": "13301408646379134",
         "date_modified": "0",
         "guid": "82b081ec-3dd3-529c-8475-ab6c344590dd",
         "id": "2",
         "name": "Other bookmarks",
         "type": "folder"
      },
      "synced": {
         "children": [  ],
         "date_added": "13301408646379137",
         "date_modified": "0",
         "guid": "4cf2e351-0e85-532b-bb37-df045d8f8d0f",
         "id": "3",
         "name": "Mobile bookmarks",
         "type": "folder"
      }
   },
   "version": 1
}
```

i would like to be able to add to nodes under "bookmark_bar" and "other":

So my code from reading these 2 files and stroring them as JSON is:

```
    $data1 = Get-Content $BackupStore/Bookmarks-chrome.json | ConvertFrom-Json
    $data2 = Get-Content $BackupStore/Bookmarks-edge.json  | ConvertFrom-Json
    
    $store1=$data1.roots
    $store2=$data2.roots
```

How should i proceed now combining them in their respective nodes?

Comment: I guess what you want is `foreach ($bookmark in $data2.roots.bookmark_bar.children) { $data1.roots.bookmark_bar.children += $bookmark }`. Same for `.roots.other.children`

Comment: Thank you very much for this. Problem solved. I had a look into the documentation and could not sass out anything to be honest. What is the best way to go about learning these operations in depth? Apart obviously from trial and error...

Comment: Difficult to advise on that.. However, the best way of learning is by trial and error, reading other people's code here on SO and googling for tutorials/videos can also be a great help like [here](https://techgenix.com/json-with-powershell/) or [there](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/explain-json-format-in-powershell)

Comment: Good stuff - thanks again..